# Moving average for a date without data in the table

Tags: mysql, moving-average

Hello I have below data for a table and I'm looking for moving average.

Original Data

```
date    qty 
06/11/15    5   
08/11/15    7   
09/11/15    8   
10/11/15    12  
11/11/15    34  
15/11/15    45  
16/11/15    12  
17/11/15    7
```

The moving average should consider last 90 days of data and give me the average of the current data like below

```
Moving Average Data     
date    qty movingAvg
06/11/15    5   5
07/11/15    0   2.5
08/11/15    7   4
09/11/15    8   5
10/11/15    12  6.4
11/11/15    34  11
12/11/15    0   9.43
13/11/15    0   8.25
14/11/15    0   7.33
15/11/15    45  11.1
16/11/15    12  11.18
17/11/15    7   10.83
```

The query I'm using

```
SELECT t1.date,t1.qty, AVG(t2.qty) AS 'movingAvg'
FROM tbl t1
JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.company_id=t2.company_id 
AND DATEDIFF(t1.date, t2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 90
WHERE t1.company_id=1234
GROUP BY t1.date
ORDER BY t1.date;
```

which is ignoring date without entry, I want to include them as well.

Comment: As a start, store dates as dates

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `Str_to_date` like that

```
Str_to_date(t1.date,'%d/%m/%y')
```

or change this

```
DATEDIFF(Str_to_date(t1.date,'%d/%m/%y'), Str_to_date(t2.date,'%d/%m/%y'))
```

> MySQL `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert a string into a date time
>   value

Comment: Hi Rahautos, i want to include the entries without data on a particular day like 07,12,13,14